# Where to get feedback on proposals for new optimizers to be added to OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

I am working on developing some multiobjective optimization algorithms, and would like to have them considered for integration in OpenMDAO. How can I reach out to the development team for feedback?

Comment: Submit a pull request on their GitHub page.  https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenMDAO project](https://github.com/openmdao/openmdao) hosts a separate repository where they consider and discuss [proposals for enhancements (POEMs)](https://github.com/openmdao/poems). Anyone can submit a POEM, but the developers get final say on whether or not the POEM is accepted.

You should post a POEM there if you want your algorithms considered. However, the developers are typically hesitant to accept POEMS with new algorithms into the main code base, since they would then have to take ownership for maintaining them.

Instead, you should consider releasing your algorithms as an [OpenMDAO plugin](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.2.1/features/experimental/plugins.html) instead. This would let you have a stand alone repository, but make your code usable by the community.

Comment: thank you very much, I want to know if it means that the new proposed algorithms can be added into the openmdao as a plugin?

Comment: Plugins are stand alone repositories, which users can install on their own. Once installed, the plugins can interact with OpenMDAO in the exact same manner as any code in the main OpenMDAO repository. 

So in your case, users could import optimization drivers from your library and use them on their openmdao models. The only difference would be that they need to install a second package. Your algorithms would not ship as part of OpenMDAO.